# Handling django-rest-auth auth token on a client webapp developed using django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, access-token, django-rest-auth

I have developed an api wgich is protected using token authentication. I m able to fetch the token once when logging in to the webapp. The token is stored in a cookie. Every call to the api contains the token. But what after the token expires?
I've been unable to figure that out. How should I request a new one? I know I can request a new token using the login credentials. But what if the token expires every 300 seconds?
And what is the ideal duration before it expires?
Have I kept it too short-lived?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When the token expires, you must prompt the user to log in again to fetch a new one.  Handle this client side.

Comment: How long shall the token be valid ideally?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780955/django-rest-framework-jwt-how-to-change-the-token-expiration-time-when-logged-i